# Clone last N changesets (mercurial)

Tags: mercurial

I have big repository.

```
 ...
  |
 601
  |
 602
 |   \
606   603
 |     |
607   604
 |     |
608   605
 |  \ |
610  609
```

I need create new repository after changeset 601.

How i can do it?

Answer (score 0):

This is not available in Mercurial. There was a project called [Shallow Clones](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/ShallowClone) but it seems it has been abandoned.

However this questions has been asked already on SO and you will find some good leads/workarounds here:

[Can I clone just the latest changesets of a repository instead of the entire history?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21762447/can-i-clone-just-the-latest-changesets-of-a-repository-instead-of-the-entire-his)

Hope it'll help.

Answer (score 0):

You can't clone part of history, but you can try bundle|unbundle cycle (and yes, when you'll unbundle into the empty repo, some headaches are expected)